# can cntlm hashes be cracked with hashcat?

Tags: hash, hashcat

I generate the hash of password 'aaa' with cntlm:

```
$ cntlm -H
Password:<aaa>
PassLM          E3C5D4926C65EFDE552C4BCA4AEBFB11
PassNT          1DBEF96BD40C7430A8595B4D6FE91009
PassNTLMv2      4400F4365FB00A5291008FF563C23C5E    # Only for user '', domain ''
```

Then I put these hashes into hash.aaa file and do:

```
hashcat --force hash.aaa -a 3 -m 1000 'aaa'
```

Tried other hash types after -m. Nothing succeeds.
Does anyone know the "mapping" between cntlm hash types
and hashcat's? In particular I need the one named "PassNTLMv2" in cntlm.
Or, more generically, is there any way of identifying the
hash type when the password is known?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles on this when trying to crack cntlm generated hashes - The hashes outputted by CNTLM use a reverse character set (0=F,1=E etc.), so you just need to correct them, then you can use the hash in hashcat.

Comment: You should post this as a comment